# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Session MaxAge is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies, session-timeout, max-age

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365) <--- 1 year;
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

app.UseSession();
```

in Startup.cs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEMZ7.png)

But, after 30 minutes it will be empty.

Comment: Session state is stored in memory. Your application is probably being restarted, perhaps when IIS recycles the app-pool.

Comment: Could you please try using `options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);` instead of `MaxAge`